# HTML loop in Chameleon similar to that in PHP

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon

I used to use the if statement enclosing HTML in my php pages to repeatedly produce HTML units with similar content. Would like to know the equivalent in Python Pyramid.

eg:

```
<?php if($i<10): ?>
<div class=''x1>
<?php echo $i?>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Want to do similarly in Pyramid framework in python within a chameleon .pt template file.

Currently doing this:

```
 Post1="<div class='posts'>\n<h1 class='content-subhead'> Posted on "
    Post2="</h1><!-- A single blog post --><section class='post'><header class='post-header'><h2 class='post-title'><a href='blog/"
    Post3="</h2><p class='post-meta'>By Blaise M Crowly</p></header><div class='post-description'>"
    Post4="</div><a href='blog/"
    Post5="'>Read More </a></section></div> "
    Post = ""

    phazer = cur.fetchall()
    for each in phazer:
        Text = strip_tags(each[2])
        Text = Text[:400]
        Post=Post+Post1+str(each[4])+" "+str(each[5])+" "+str(each[6])+" "+str(each[7])+Post2+str(each[1])+"'> "+str(each[0])+"</a>"+Post3+str(Text)+Post4+str(each[1])+Post5

    return render_to_response('blaise:templates/blog.pt',{'posts':Post},request=request)
```

Comment: creating a variable and attaching everything including the html tags before passing it to the renderer

Comment: Posting the code you have will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: What template language are you using? Mako, Jinja2, Chameleon ZPT? Pyramid can use all of those and more, but the syntax between those template languages can vary widely.

Comment: @MartijnPieters using Chameleon.

Comment: @IanAuld  added my code to the question

Comment: That logic should be moved to the template itself. In Pyramid, anytime you're constructing HTML fragments in response handlers is a sign of a serious problem in your design.

Comment: Off Topic: I am really curious why people love to down vote? There should be a comment field to fill up why someone is downvoting! Apologies for irrelevant stuffs!

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun: That's a discussion for meta (and has already [been discussed at length](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes).

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun: but the tooltip on the downvote button is a good indicator as to why someone might downvote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: thanks for the info. It would be really beneficial at least for the newcomers!

Comment: @MaxNoel I know, am wondering how to get it done.

Comment: @BMC Your templating engine should provide a looping construct: use that. If it doesn't, use another one (I recommend Mako).